# How to diagnose netstat: no namelist

Tags: networking, linux-networking, truenas, netstat, jail

I had to replace an NIC on my HP Proliant Microserver, running FreeNAS 9.3

In my crashplan jail, I now get "netstat: no namelist" as a response when I execute the netstat command.  How to I diagnose this?  Could it be that the virtual NIC epair for the jail is still bound to the old NIC?

Comment: I ran into this recently after I upgraded from 9.3 to 9.10 - it looks like the binaries in the jails are not updated. For example `ls -la /usr/bin/netstat` on the base system returns a different file size from running the same command in a jail - not sure how to fix it yet. Simply copying the binary didn't work (complains about library mismatches). I suspect one would have to re-create the jails.